# MySql group by two columns

Tags: mysql

i am just begin learning mysql for php! i have a problem with query mysql to get data team from table
i have a table with the fields 
table name (team)

```
id, OPPONENT, COMPETITION
```

data table (team) like this

```
**id**  **OPPONENT**    **COMPETITION**
     1      barcelona         real madrid 
     2      barcelona         Villarreal   
     3      real madrid       ruby
```

i want  write query to get table like this

```
 **team**
 barcelona
 Villarreal
 real madrid 
 ruby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table should have foreign key of your teams and you would simply select teams name in teams table.

Anyway, if you want to do it that way, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT opponent AS team FROM table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT competition AS team FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.opponent team FROM (
    SELECT opponent team
    FROM tbl
    UNIOUN ALL
    SELECT competition team
    FROM tbl
) t
```